# Sending Multitouch report descriptor and input report to Android phone (jelly bean) via AOA 2.0

Tags: android

I need to send Multitouch report descriptor and corresponding input reports to Android phone (Jelly Bean version) via AOA 2.0 protocol. I am able to send the descriptor and input report successfully, but android device considering only one touch. Any help regarding this would be a great helpful to me.

I am doing in this way:

1. Switch the phone to AOA mode
2. Send Multitouch report descriptor in a single command
3. send Report data of 14 bytes which contains first touch `(x,y)` and second touch `(x,y)` information.